# Aggregating values on JSONB field

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to perform specific queries on my table to a jsonb field but having trouble to get the final output as an int.
Assuming that each row as a JSONB field with the format below I want to obtain a the total number of orders by each product.

```
{ 
    "Product A": {
        "orders": {"total": 2, "stuff": 3} 
        "..."
    },
    { 
    "Product B": {
        "orders": {"total": 1, "stuff": 1} 
        "..."
    },
    { 
    "Product C": {
        "orders": {"total": 5, "stuff": 0} 
        "..."
    }
}
```

I've done the query:

```
select key as product, value::json->'orders'->'total' as total
from table, jsonb_each_text(json_field)
group by key, value;
```

With this I'm able to obtain the total by product:

```
product      | total
Product A    | 10
Product B    | 15
Product C    | 0
```

However it seems the total is a jsonb field, I've tried to use (value::json->'orders'->'total')::numeric but it says the cast is not possible. Can you help please?

Comment: You should use `jsonb_each(json_field)` and `value->'order'->>'total'`. That you can cast to numeric (but only if that field is really a JSON number, everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do it:

Needed to convert to text before converting to numeric like:

```
(value::json->'orders'->'total')::text::numeric
```

Comment: Or just: `(value::json->'orders'->>'total')::numeric`